# Azure static public IP not appearing in IIS's bindings

Tags: azure, iis, azure-web-app-service

I have a Windows Server 2019 Virtual Machine hosted on Azure.  This VM does have a static IP.
I am trying to deploy a website on the server and only the internal IP is showing in bindings:
[image]

I have added the appropriate inbound rule in the Azure portal for port 80.
How can i get the public IP address to appear in bindings?

Comment: That list can only show internal IP addresses, as the items are IP addressed bind to the network interfaces of the machine. Traffic from external IP addresses are forwarded to internal IP addresses by network devices (gateways and so on), which is out of IIS's control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you dont need to do that, just listen on all IP addresses, that would work just fine

Comment: It's more like a comment, as it does not explain why external IP addresses are not there ("All Unassigned" does not include external IP addresses either).

Comment: because they are not exposed to your vm, they are being routed by external entities to the private IP address of your VM